# How to make iPhone camera silent?

Tags: iphone, audio, camera

On my iPhone, the camera shutter sound follows the ring/silent switch. However, I'd like the camera to be **always** silent, regardless of whether incoming calls & messages make a sound. Is there any way to configure it that way?

(Non-jailbroken iPhone 4 with latest iOS.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the mute switch on the side of the phone.  The camera shutter sound is controlled by the ringer volume, since the mute switch mutes the ringer the shutter sound is also mute.  However, you are asking an optional permanent solution.  So far there is none.  The application doesn't have any additional options within the app or within System Preferences.

Digging into the app store there is a simple camera application called *Secret Camera - Taking Photo Secretly* for $1.99. [Apple Store Link](http://itunes.apple.com/app/secret-camera-taking-photo/id438199781?mt=8) It looks like it functions like the normal Camera application, but reading its description it doesn't explicitly mention a shutter mute option.  I assume this is an implied feature due to the app's name.

Comment: Unfortunately, this (first part of your answer) is not a valid answer for iPhones originating in Korea or Japan. The mute button does not mute the camera shutter sound. More answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the best solution, but I use an old headphone jack.  Essentially, I cut the end of the cord up to the point where the jack is.  I use the jack as a "sound" blocker.  Does wonders if you don't mind a little jack sticking out at the bottom lol

Comment: Does this work on iPhone 7 era hardware in regions like Japan or Korea where the sounds are expected to play each shutter release?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's an option to disable the camera shutter sound, but [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5101268_turn-off-camera-noise-iphone.html) is a guide on how to disable the sound.

Comment: Problem with that guide is, the MobileFinder app is (no longer?) available in the App Store. (Given Apple's restrictive policies, I'd actually be surprised if a such file manager apps were available.)

Comment: (On jailbroken iPhones renaming the photoShutter.caf file would probably be a piece of cake, but personally I'd rather not jailbreak.)

Comment: I'm not sure about MobileFiner, but there are other apps, like iExplorer (http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), that can be used on iPhones that aren't jailbroken (I used it once to upload a Japanese dictionary into the Kindle app for iPhone and it worked perfectly).

Comment: Hmm, [iExplorer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iexplorer/id307733225?mt=8) indeed is on App Store. (Though the reviews don't paint too good a picture of it.) If you have the app, you could try if it's possible to rename files under `System/Library/Audio/UISounds` with it... (Somehow I still doubt that.)

Comment: This was done a few months ago on my girlfriend Mac so I don't have it installed myself, but the app is 100% free and downloadable via the website I posted in my previous comment :)

Comment: Here's another guide with more detail: http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/25/turn-off-iphone-camera-sound/

Answer (score 0):

Initially, silencing the camera was a simple flick of the physical mute switch, however many governments now regulate this and the os will bypass many efforts to silence the capture noise.

- [iPhone makes shutter sound when taking photos despite being on mute](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275118/iphone-makes-shutter-sound-when-taking-photos-despite-being-on-mute)

This may or may not work long term since video capture is typically silent and extracting high quality stills is easy. Also, Live Photo feature further blurs the line between a photo and a video that pre-records the scene before you trigger a “photo” from the “camera”.

Answer (score -2):

just flip the the phone's ring/silent switch to silent.

Comment: Please read the question before answering: "the camera shutter sound follows the ring/silent switch. However, I'd like the camera to be **always** silent"