# iPhone makes shutter sound when taking photos despite being on mute

Tags: iphone, camera, screen-capture, sound-volume

I recently purchased a refurbished iPhone 6. It's been set up from my old device's iCloud backup and updated to iOS 10.2.1.

Unfortunately, [despite being set to silent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUrV3.png) via the physical mute switch, my iPhone will make a shutter sound whenever I take a photo using the built in camera. I'm using my device in the United States, so [country laws shouldn't be an issue](https://www.engadget.com/2016/09/30/japans-noisy-iphone-problem/).

**Why would an iPhone camera be making a shutter sound while set to silent?**

Edit: Worth noting that [using the mute switch](http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/25/turn-off-iphone-camera-sound/) worked for my last iPhone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible the refurbished unit originated from Japan or Korea, where the setting of the mute switch is deliberately ignored by the Camera app. See [this article at engadget](https://www.engadget.com/2016/09/30/japans-noisy-iphone-problem/).

Comment: After some research I believe this to be the answer. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to find out for certain.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://recomhub.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-iphone-and-ipad-in-ios-10-camera-shutter-sound/) about turning off the shutter sound:

> For those in the United States, turning off the camera sound is illegal, as the law states that cell phones containing digital cameras must make a sound when taking a picture.

You should be able to turn the sound off by pressing the volume down button all the way until it goes into vibrate mode.  It looks like you could have done that already.

At this point, your options are

1. Use a 3rd-party camera app that allows you to control the shutter sound.
2. Use `Assistive Touch` to [disable the sound prior to taking a picture](http://tool-box.info/blog/archives/2097-Disable-camera-shutter-sound-on-iOS-10.0.1.html).

   1. Go to `Settings -> General -> Accessibility`
   2. Scroll to the bottom and select `Accessibility Shortcut -> AssistiveTouch`.
   3. Back-out of that menu item so you're in `Accessibility` again.  Scroll up and select `AssistiveTouch` and turn it on.
   4. Enter `Customize Top Level Menu` and remove icons until there's only one left. Tap that icon and select **Mute** (if you leave two or more icons here it will not work).

According to that site:

> When you triple-click the home button, a small floating AssistiveTouch button will appear on the screen. When you press it, the system sound will be muted completely, including the camera shutter sound and alarm. Pressing the AssistiveTouch button again will re-enable the system sound, and triple-clicking the home button will hide the AssistiveTouch button.

Comment: The entire point is that muting my phone has no effect on the shutter noise

Comment: I understand but this is the only way I could find that, according to the author, would silence the shutter sound.  Did you try it and did it not work for you?

Comment: Yes. Lowering or silencing the ring volume has no effect on the shutter sound

Comment: That's strange because when i follow those exact steps I listed above, I don't get any shutter sound when I take a picture.  I have an iPhone 2 with iOS 10.2.1.

Comment: There in lies the issue. Those steps worked on my last phone, but not my current phone. IconDaemon proposed that my phone may have been made for a foreign country where turning off the shutter sound is prohibited, even if your phone is on silent.

Comment: That article is 100% incorrect (as of 2018). There is no current legal requirement that camera's create a sound when taking a picture in the US. The only thing I've ever seen about Congress even thinking about legislating it is this single bill, which had zero co-sponsors and was absolutely ignored by the rest of Congress and obviously never become: https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/111/hr414/text

Answer (score 0):

You can use camera app **B612** to take photo without sound. Because in **B612** have option to mute sound camera.